# cannot find module webpack-dev-server.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm having an issue while running simple todo app by run the command webpack-dev-server in the git bash. This is my webpack.config.js

```
var webpack =  require("webpack");
    var path = require("path");

    module.exports = {
        devtool : 'inline-source-map',
        entry   :[
                'webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8080/',
                'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
                './src'
        ],
        output :{
            path:path.join(__dirname,'public'),
            filename :'bundle.js'
        },
        resolve :{
            modulesDirectories :['./node_modules','src'],
            extensions :['','.js']
        },
        module:{
            loaders :[{
                test : /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude :/node_modules/,
                loaders:['react-hot','babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015']
            }]
        },
        plugins :[
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
            new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
        ]

    };
```

The actual is: `error cannot find node modules inside the git Directory` I have installed webpack-dev-server locally.

I have attached the error in the screenshot
    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uexvg.png

Answer (score 0):

The readme.md tell you to go to localhost:8080 but https://github.com/michaelcheng429/react-tutorial-todos/blob/master/server.js file is set to localhost:3000. So go to localhost:3000 and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see. i have made few changes on your code and its working on port 8080.

https://github.com/OnlyRefat/Example

You need to install both webpack and webpack-dev-server globally and locally.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need `'webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8080/'` as an entry point in your config. Try removing it.

You might also need to install webpack globally `npm install webpack-dev-server -g` and then try running `webpack-dev-server`

Comment: Thanks Geraint !  I tried the solution you provided but still i am getting the same error. i have cloned the code from [link] (https://github.com/michaelcheng429/react-tutorial-todos)

Comment: try deleting your `node_modules` folder and doing `npm install` again. look out for any errors while doing npm install

Comment: Geraint  Thank you for your valuable support ! i deleted node_modules and i did npm install but still the same problem